# Unable to read NSUserDefaults from Watch when iPhone app launched

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I'm trying to figure out what state the Watch is in when the iPhone app launches.

On the watch, there are 3 buttons. When a button is pressed the following code is run:

```
if let watchDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.mywatchkit") {
        watchDefaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "intstate")
        watchDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

Then when the app is launched, in the *viewDidLoad()* method I try to retrieve the state:

```
if let watchDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.mywatchkit"){

        let currentState = watchDefaults.integerForKey("intstate")

        if currentState != 0 {

            stateLabel.text = currentState.description
            switch currentState {
            case 1: 
                //do what state 1 needs
                println("current state is \(currentState)")

            case 2: 
                //do what state 2 needs
                println("current state is \(currentState)")
            case 3: 
                //do what state 3 needs
                println("current state is \(currentState)")


            default:
                println("default state")

            }

        } else {

            watchDefaults.setInteger(3, forKey: "intstate")
            stateLabel.text = "current state is 3"
        }

    }
```

Sadly I'm always getting the string "???" Am I missing something fundamental?

Because it returns 0 if there is no value and there for it will never be nil. So you just need to check if it is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use NSUserDefaults method called stringForKey() to load your Strings. Just use the same method you used for the suitName (if let) to safely unwrap your String for that key. Try like this:

```
if let watchDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.mywatchkit") {
    watchDefaults.setObject("buttonX", forKey: "state")
}
if let watchDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.mywatchkit"){
    if let currentState = watchDefaults.stringForKey("state") {
        println(currentState)  // "buttonX"
    }
     else {
        println(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was as simple as changing the retrieval from objectForKey to stringForKey.

Comment: Well it worked for about 5 minutes consistently then started to give me inconsistent results again.

Comment: I think you should never need to sync . The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: So I redid the code to use integers for states instead of strings. Using strings was inconsistent. Now it works in every case **except** when the _viewDidLoad()_ method is run the first time.

Comment: Can you show how you are loading your values inside viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I added the current code to the original post. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No need to cast as Int when loading using integerForKey

Comment: It never returns nil it returns 0

Comment: Return Value The integer value associated with the specified key. If the specified key does not exist, this method returns 0.

Comment: Resuming it does NOT returns an optional

Comment: func integerForKey(_ defaultName: String) -> Int

Comment: You can't check if it is == nil

Answer (score 2):

You are using different key names in your code: `state` and `intstate`

Comment: I'm curious if this was actually the problem here.